# Where is the source sink of SWI-Prolog?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have a prolog file test.pl on the DESKTOP. And I tried to use SWI-Prolog to load it.
I input

```
consult([test]).
```

And the error is:

```
?- consult([test]).
ERROR: source_sink `test' does not exist
true.
```

So which path should I put the test.pl file in? Or how can I use SWI-Prolog to load it?

Comment: Mine is Mac OS  10.15

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure SWI-Prolog's current working directory is the one you expect, or you need to specify a file name including a path.

To query the current directory:

```
?- working_directory(Current, Current).
Current = '/home/isabelle/'.
```

You can pass the name of a new directory as the second argument:

```
?- working_directory(Old, '/home/isabelle/Desktop').
Old = '/home/isabelle/'.
```

After the above, checking the now current directory:

```
?- working_directory(Current, Current).
Current = '/home/isabelle/Desktop/'.
```

If I have a file `/home/isabelle/Desktop/test.pl`, I can now consult it as `?- [test].` or `?- consult(test).` or `?- consult([test]).`

Alternatively, without changing directories, I can use the absolute file name:

```
?- consult('/home/isabelle/Desktop/test.pl').
true.
```

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful! One more question, I want to use Aleph to construct a theory, what command should I use? I tried consult[test]. and the result is 'true', but I can't see the output result.

Comment: If that is helpful, you can click the upvote arrow or "accept" the answer to show that it solved your problem ;-) Sorry, I don't know anything about Aleph.